# Using JSR303 validator with AJAX dynamically generated webpage

Tags: java, ajax, model-view-controller, jsf-2, bean-validation

I'm having quite a pickle with a JSF2.0, richfaces 4, MVC based website.
I have a webpage where the user is suposed to input his adress.

However he can choose to input only 1 or 3 adresses.
At first only 1 adress is displayed, then by checking some checkboxes he can choose to add more adresses.

[image: the page]

[image: the code]

But if I use JSR303 validator then validation constraints will be checked even for non generated adress.

Is there a way to add contition to those validator? like, @NotEmpty(if="chekboxe1")

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue and there is no straightforward solution (google for keywords: multi-field JSR 303 custom validation annotations).

Although the usage of JSR 303 is very appealing, we could also argue weather multi-property validation on the data side makes sense. I am saying multi-property because you are approaching to the validation process from the data and not from the input (filed). Therefore, you can run into a case where certain multi-validation will make sense for one user (record creation), but not for the other (editing by admin).

In my opinion, you should use JSR 303 for very basic checking (for example, if data is compatible with the database constraints), but for the front-end specifics I would use regular JSF validation process.

Comment: Well I guess I'll use only JSF validator then, don't want to mix 2 tech.